# Vbscript: Convert text string in small pieces and put it into a array

Tags: arrays, string, text, vbscript, split

I need to break a long text string into smaller pieces approximately once every 500 characters (not a special character), forming an array of all the sentences and then put them together separated by a specific character (eg / /). Something as follows:

"This text is a very very large text."

So, I get:

```
arrTxt(0) = "This is"
arrTxt(1) = "a very"
arrTxt(2) = "very large text"
...
```

And finally:

```
response.write arrTxt(0) & "//" & arrTxt(1) & "//" & arrTxt(2)...
```

Due to my limited knowledge of classic asp, the closest I came to a desired result was the following:

```
length = 200
strText = "This text is a very very large."
lines = ((Len (input) / length) - 1)
For i = 0 To (Len (lines) - 1)
txt = Left (input, (i * length)) & "/ /"
response.write txt
Next
```

However, this returns a repeated and overlapping text string: "this is / / this is a / / this is a text //...

Any idea with vbscript? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a try:

```
Dim strText as String
Dim strTemp as String
Dim arrText()
Dim iSize as Integer
Dim i as Integer

strText = "This text is a very very large."
iSize = Len(stText) / 500
ReDim arrText(iSize)
strTemp = strText

For i from 0 to iSize - 1
  arrText(i) = Left(strTemp, 500)
  strTemp = Mid(strTemp, 501)
Next i

WScript.Echo Join(strTemp, "//")
```

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation. Unfortunately, it did not work. I got the following error "Array fixed or temporarily locked" in 'ReDim Preserve arrText(UBound(arrText) + 1)'. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @afalzolo: i changed my code so it will be a dynamic array instead of a fixed one

Comment: Nop, I get the same error. Also, if I declare the variables as a string (Dim strText **as** String), I get the following error: "End of statement expected" in "As" ????

Comment: i edited my answer for another try. i can't understand you got the `Array fixed or temporarily locked` error. I can't test right here but i'll have a try tomorrow

Comment: @afalzolo JMax has wrote some VBA / VB code with an ASP object (Response). VBscript supports only late binding (declaration without "as" keyword and date type, e.g. Dim strText, Dim iSize), and WScript.Echo be used for the output.

Comment: Cuz I'm busy and lack of time I made a choice for simplicity: strText = Split(strText , "."). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin: thanks for the explanation! i'll correct my code with your tip

Answer (score 2):

Without using an array, you can just build the string as you go

```
Const LIMIT = 500
Const DELIMITER = "//"
' your input string - String() creates a new string by repeating the second parameter by the given
' number of times
dim INSTRING: INSTRING = String(500, "a") & String(500, "b") & String(500, "c")


dim current: current = Empty
dim rmainder: rmainder = INSTRING 
dim output: output = Empty
' loop while there's still a remaining string
do while len(rmainder) <> 0
    ' get the next 500 characters
    current = left(rmainder, LIMIT)
    ' remove this 500 characters from the remainder, creating a new remainder
    rmainder = right(rmainder, len(rmainder) - len(current))
    ' build the output string
    output  = output  & current & DELIMITER
loop
' remove the lastmost delimiter
output = left(output, len(output) - len(DELIMITER))
' output to page
Response.Write output
```

If you really need an array, you can then `split(output, DELIMITER)`

Comment: Your code worked perfectly for my purpose. I really thank you.